# Java Watchable check for events forever

Tags: java

How to set java watchable to check for events forever ? I mean I'm getting the event's simply with if ..

```
 for (WatchEvent event : events) {
               boolean terminate_or = false;

                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString());
                    event.
                }
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
                    terminate_or = true;
                }
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                    System.out.println("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
                    terminate_or = true;
                }
            }
```

But it get's them only once, and then terminate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while(true) { //your code }. Make sure you have some exit condition in while loop else this will be infinite.

Comment: What you are looking for?? see [while True](http://www.coderanch.com/t/410636/java/java/while-true).

Comment: I know what is while(true), but i'm asking about that watchable how can it be done ?

Comment: see [WatchKeyJavaDoc](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html) It has example you are looking for.